# Individual segmentation mask for instances (blender 3.0)

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, masking, instances

I am working on an application where I want to create segmentation masks of individual instances in a scene. I've created these instances by using the 'instance on points' node in geometry nodes. The collection of objects that I use contains up to 100 individual objects and the number of vertices varies between objects.
[image: Simplified geometry nodes setup]

What I would like to achieve is an individual segmentation image for every single image (see example below). However I can't seem to figure out how to isolate one single instance. Hopefully someone has an idea about how to achieve this, thanks in advance guys!

[image: segmentation masks]

Comment: your text is quite complicated to read...did i understood you right, you just want to see one instance per frame? is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to render one image with all instances + one mask image per instance. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Unfortunately no. What do you mean by mask image? I just know mask from compositor of mask modifier. And your examples just show one image. How does your „mask image“ look like?

Comment: Ok, mask image might be a confusing choice of words for Blender.

For every scene, I want to render:
(a) one image with all objects; this is the top image in my examples. and (b) one image per instance in black and white, where white indicates the instance. (that's what I meant with 'mask image'); these are the bottom three images in my examples.

Comment: @Chris I think the screenshots clearly show what a mask image per instance could be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show "single" instances like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

for a "cheap" mask image you could e.g. use emission material with strength 3

[image]

[image]

then use the material in your GN tree:

[image]

Comment: +1 I guess this is quite close to what @teun_Q wants... if the _Color Management_ would be set to _Standard_ instead of _Filmic_, an _Emission Strength_ of 1 should be sufficient. Maybe an _Override Material_ with emission set for the scene (so that each object can keep it's own material) together with animating the Index (i.e. the "Equal to" value) with #frame-1 to cycle through all objects. Then it's possible to render an image sequence with one instance visible per frame.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate suggestions! I'll try this method!